# How to make scrollable horizontal calendar?

Tags: jquery, django, datatables

[image]

I want to make a calendar in Django using jQuery Datatables with fixed 'First_name' and 'Last_name' columns.

So far I have fixed columns with names by using django template tag:

```html
{{for employers in Employers }}
<tr>
<td>{{employers.first_name}}</td>
<td>{{employers.last_name}}</td>
</tr>
```

But how I can make scrollable horizontal calendar with months?

Comment: Have you seen [django-scheduler](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler)?

Comment: I've seen it but, I dont think this offer what I want + I think it would be hard to customize it than make a new calendar by using jQuery Datatables.
But I could be wrong.

Comment: Just tried django-scheduler. It's definitely not what I'm looking for.

Comment: What did you finally use?